# How to set constraints on UDT in SQL Server 2005 - 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-design, datatypes

I'm creating my UDT:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Code]
FROM VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

As RULES and DEFAULTS are considered deprecated, what is the recommended way to set constraint on my type to make sure that columns defined from this type contain only specific characters?

Comment: Do you know what needs to be done if you need to change the column width from 20 to, let's say, 30 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to truly centralize/encapsulate this kind of logic (which is what I assume you're trying to do) is to use a CLR type. The good news it that this solution works with 2005+.

One alternative is to centralize the validation logic into a UDF, and then create individual check constraints that reference the UDF. If you're not using CLR already, this may be the best solution.

`CREATE TYPE` is very limited: when referencing a system type, it's just a type alias and nothing more. It would be nice to, for example, declare a check constraint (or something similar) that's associated with the type itself, but this is currently not implemented.